# Send image to another application

Tags: android

I want to know if that is a way in the moment i take a picture, send it in background to other app, like a vault, keepsafe or appprotector?

Without the user has to go to gallery and click in share with others apps above . I would like that was automatic, without use "app chooser".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to ask the authors of your proposed "vault, keepsafe or approtector" if they support some custom API for this. There are no conventions in Android for sending content to another app in the background. In the foreground, you are welcome to use `ACTION_SEND`, or `ShareActionProvider`, etc.